# Calculation of LST overestimates values

Tags: qgis

I am trying to retrieve LST from Landsat 8 data, after writing my script, it shows very good results until I estimate the emissivity of my study area, but when I run the following part,

```js
var LST = thermal. Expression( '(Tb/(1+(0.00115*( Tb/ 1.438))*log(Ep)))-273.15' , {'Tb' : thermal.select('B10'), 'Ep' : Em.select('EMM') }).rename('LST');
```

I get overestimated values. What's wrong with my code?

---

This is the code I used for my analysis, It showing me values as min: -243 max: -242, even for non glaciated areas also.

---

Before this, I uploaded the image collection and removed the cloud cover

```
// image reduction
{
var image = col.median().clip(geometry);
print(image, 'image');
Map.addLayer(image, vizParams2);
}
//median and ndvi
{
var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5' , 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
var ndviParams = { min : -1, max : 1, palette: ['blue' , 'white' , 'green']};
print(ndvi, 'ndvi');
Map.addLayer (ndvi , ndviParams, 'ndvi');
}

// select thermal band

var thermal = image.select('B10').multiply(0.1);
var B10Params = { min: 291.918, max: 302.382, palette: [ 'blue' , 'white' , 'green']};
Map.addLayer( thermal, B10Params, 'thermal')

// min and max of ndvi
var min = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
reducer : ee.Reducer.min(),
geometry: geometry,
scale : 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(min, 'min')
{
var max = ee.Number(ndvi.reduceRegion({
reducer : ee.Reducer.max(),
geometry: geometry,
scale : 30,
maxPixels: 1e9
}).values().get(0));
print(max, 'max')
}
// fractional vegetation 
{
var fv = ( ndvi.subtract(min).divide(max.subtract(min))).pow(ee.Number(2)).rename('fv');
print(fv, 'fv');
Map.addLayer(fv);
}
//emissivity
var a = ee.Number(0.004);
var b = ee.Number(0.984);
var Em=fv.multiply(a).add(b).rename('EMM');
var imageVisParam3 = {min : 0.9865619146722164 , max : 0.989699971371314}
Map.addLayer(Em , imageVisParam3 , 'EMM');
//lst

var LST = thermal.expression(
'(Tb/(1+(0.00115*( Tb/ 1.438))*log(Ep)))-273.15' , {'Tb' : thermal.select('B10'),
'Ep' : Em.select('EMM')
}).rename('LST');

var viz= { min: -3 , max : 35, palette: [ 'red' , 'orange' , 'pink', 'brown' , 'green']}
Map.addLayer(LST, {min: 0, max: 350, palette: ['green', 'blue']},'LST');
```

Comment: Please share your entire code.